# Не обрабаывается цикл внутри While(true)

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api, while, циклы

Принимаю данные с сервера. Данные приходят, при дебаге он их видит в локальных переменных. Но дальше идет цикл обработки, и он почему-то не работает.

Причем после точки останова вообще весь цикл (внешний) перестает выполняться.

```
void workLongPoll(GetLongPollDate LPollDate)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string s = WebRequest.Get(string.Format("http://{0}?act=a_check&key={1}&ts={2}&wait=25&mode=2", LPollDate.server, LPollDate.key, LPollDate.ts));
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(s);
        LPollDate.ts = o.Value<string>("ts");
        JArray updates = (JArray)o["updates"];
        foreachUpdate(updates);
    }
}

void foreachUpdate(JArray updates)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < updates.Count)
    {
        updateLongPoll upd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<updateLongPoll>(updates[i].ToString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо нажать кнопку продолжения выполнения

Comment: А что означает «не работает»? Может, вы блокируете UI-поток?

Comment: У меня стоят точки останова в цикле. В функцию freachUpdate программа даже не заходит (на ней не останавливается точка), и после продолжения программы главный цикл перестает выполняться (точки останова в нем не срабатывают более)